# Is it OK to use BUILD_MODE in a make invocation?

Tags: c++, travis-ci, gnu-make

We are working on a Travis CI setup for a C++ library that is built using GNUmake. The configuration file is located at [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp/blob/master/.travis.yml). Its a Git clone of the library used for testing and experimentation.

The config file has a few library configurations in the `matrix`:

```
matrix:
  - BUILD_MODE="shared"
  - BUILD_MODE="static"
  - BUILD_MODE="no-asm"
  - BUILD_MODE="asan"
  - BUILD_MODE="ubsan"
  - BUILD_MODE="valgrind"
```

Our `script` rule is:

```
script:
  - make clean &>/dev/null && make
  - ./cryptest.exe v && ./cryptest.exe tv all
```

Since we are only using `make`, the same default configuration is built for each item in the `matrix`. Build results are available at [Travis / noloader / cryptopp](https://travis-ci.org/noloader/cryptopp). The various makefile targets, like `make no-asm`, are not exercised.

My question is, is it OK to change the `script` rule to something like:

```
script:
  - make clean &>/dev/null && make "$BUILD_MODE"
  - ./cryptest.exe v && ./cryptest.exe tv all
```

Or, is exercising different configurations achieved in a different way? If so, then how do we do it?

Comment: The C++ and GNU-Make tags were added for completeness. We believe the tags have almost nothing to do with the question, but we could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, is it OK to change the script rule to something like:
>
> ```
> script:
>   - make clean &>/dev/null && make "$BUILD_MODE"
>   - ./cryptest.exe v && ./cryptest.exe tv all
> ```

This works, but ...

---

> Or, is exercising different configurations achieved in a different way? If so, then how do we do it?

... we are not sure if it is the recommended way of doing things.

If anyone knows what the best practice is, then please add an answer. I would be happy to accept it if its from a credible source, like the Travis docs.